# My Wordpress can't auto-generate the post permalink

Tags: wordpress, nginx, permalinks

Wordpress can't generate the post permalink after I type the post title. This issue happens on Nginx, after I moved from Apache.

### update

I found there were two blank lines on each .php response file.

So I just use ob_clean(); to remove these blank lines.

I just works.

For example, in wp-admin/index.php,

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/dashboard.php');
ob_clean();

wp_dashboard_setup();
```

The real reason maybe the transition method's issue, I should use binary mode to transfer the files.

Comment: Can you give more details? Like where exactly is the problem? Do you get 404 errors when you try to open for instance `http://example.com/my/page/`? Or WordPress can't create the proper permalinks(it uses `/index.php/my/page/` or `/?page_id=1`)?

Comment: Please clarify. I would guess you are talking about the view when creating a new post or page and the permalink below the Title field is not generating anything based on your input.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.It's my fault. There'are two blank lines on every .php file's response. I just add ob_clean(); before where the file is called.

Comment: what's your nginx config